# Resaltar múltiples casillas usando drag-and-drop de jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Estoy desarrollando un juego en el que el usuario puede mover piezas en un tablero. Para ello estoy utilizando HTML y jQuery UI (intenté el *drag-and-drop* de HTML5, pero fallaba en dispositivos móviles y por eso empecé a usar jQuery UI).

Quiero que cuando una pieza esté por encima del tablero, se marque de alguna manera cuál sería el destino de esa pieza en el tablero. Por ejemplo, cambiando el borde del destino de sólido a punteado, pero no consigo hacerlo.

He intentado como se especifica en la [documentación de jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#visual-feedback) para el *droppable*, añadiendo la clase `ui-droppable-hover`, pero eso falla si la ficha ocupa más de una celda del tablero, porque sólo se resalta la celda superior izquierda.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(".celda").droppable({
  classes: { "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover" }, 
  drop: function(event, ui) { 
    console.log("dropped!"); 
  }
});
$(".ficha").draggable({ 
  containment:"document", 
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

```css
#tablero {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin-right:40px;
}

.celda {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid #fafafa;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}

.ficha {
  width:60px;
  height:120px;
  float:left;
}

.ui-state-hover {
  border:2px dotted #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="tablero">
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
</div>

<div class="ficha">
  <div class="celda">1</div>
  <div class="celda">2</div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo se podrían resaltar todas las celdas que serán afectadas por el drop y no sólo la que está activa/*hover* en ese momento? (en el ejemplo de arriba deberían ser dos verticales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una opción que me funciona, pero estoy abierto a alternativas mejores (parece fallar a veces). La idea es usar los eventos [`over`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) y [`out`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out) (que no aparecen en la página de [`droppable`](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) pero sí en su [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)) para hacer lo siguiente:

1. Cuando se entra encima de un `droppable` se añade un objeto con el tamaño de la ficha
2. Cuando se sale de un `droppable` se elimina el objeto que se creó al entrar en él

Aquí dejo un demo de cómo lo estoy haciendo ahora mismo, por si a alguien le sirve como base:

```js
$(".celda").droppable({ 
  drop: function(event, ui) { 
    console.log("dropped!"); 
    $(".shadow").remove();
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).append('<div class="shadow shadow' + event.target.id + '" style="width:60px;height:120px;"></div>');
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    $(".shadow" + event.target.id).remove();
  },
});
$(".ficha").draggable({ 
  containment:"document", 
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

```css
#tablero {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin-right:40px;
}

.celda {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid #fafafa;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  position:relative;
}

.ficha {
  width:60px;
  height:120px;
  float:left;
}

.shadow {
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:-2px;
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
  z-index:2;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index:3;
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="tablero">
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
  <div class="celda"></div>
</div>

<div class="ficha">
  <div class="celda">1</div>
  <div class="celda">2</div>
</div>
```